# What is the rpc result backend in Celery?

Tags: python, django, celery

I was confused by the result backend and the broker. I use the celery in django, and set the the result backend by [the tutorial on celery docs](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html#django-celery-results-using-the-django-orm-cache-as-a-result-backend).

```
app = Celery('tasks', backend='rpc://', broker='amqp://myuser:mypassword@localhost:5672/myvhost')
```

but the backend seems useless where I have config the value of django_celery_results, so what's the relation between django_celery_results and the backend param of Celery app?

---

when I remove the backend='rpc://' from Celery param, it doesn't work. The applied task could be executed but couldn't fetch the result.

following is my django_celery_result, all the same as the tutorial:

[image: django_celery_result config]

and the Celery instance is:

```
app = Celery('tasks', broker='amqp://myuser:mypassword@localhost:5672/myvhost')
```

Comment: django_celery_results and the backend param has the same effect.

Comment: but when I remove the backend param in Celery instance constructor function, it doesn't work, what's wrong happened?

Comment: well, I think you should put up your code

Comment: did you call app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY') ?

Comment: In Celery 4x, default result backend is None, so you cannot use result.ready() etc